# Spectral clustering or hierarchical clustering for this senario?

Tags: time-series, clustering, hierarchical-clustering, spectral-analysis

I have a data set of about 40,000 time series. The length of each time series is 64. I consider these 64 as features for the data. I want to cluster data into groups which have similar time series (I want time series in each cluster to be highly correlated).

I do not know how to choose between hierarchical clustering and spectral clustering. I know that spectral clustering is good to find clusters with non convex shape and on the other hand hierarchical clustering is easier to implement.

How would you choose between these methods?

Comment: In my opinion, neither of these techniques is appropriate for clustering a time series of information. Type in "time series cluster" as keywords in the search facility on CV and you will get a wealth of threads with possible approaches to dealing with data of this type.

Comment: This doesn't seem excessively opinion-based to me.

Comment: It's hard for me to take seriously any clustering of time series that doesn't respect the time order of data. I don't understand how you propose to apply either of these methods, but neither would convince if that is not so.